# How to Extract text from MS Word?

Tags: perl, ole, win32ole

I'm trying to open a word document and just extract all the text that is in the document and display it to the user using [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ejdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm)

```
#usr/bin/perl
#OLEWord.pl

#Use string and print warnings
use strict;use warnings;
#Using OLE + OLE constants for Variants and OLE enumeration for Enumerations
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';

$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

#set the file to be opened
my $file = '/work/Test.docx';

#Create a new instance of Win32::OLE for the Word application, die if could not open the application
my $MSWord = Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application','Quit') and "Opened Word" or die     "Unable to open document ", Win32::OLE->LastError(); 
#Set the screen to Visible, so that you can see what is going on
$MSWord->{'Visible'} = 1;
#open the request file or die and print warning message
my $Doc = $MSWord->Documents->Open('C:\work\Test.docx') or die "Could not open ", $file, " Error:", Win32::OLE->LastError();

#$MSWord->ActiveDocument->SaveAs({Filename => 'AlteredTest.docx', 
                            #FileFormat => wdFormatDocument});
                            
                            
sub ShowObjs {
my $obj = shift;
foreach (sort keys %$obj) {
print "Keys: $_ - $obj->{$_}\n"; }
 }

 my $paragraphs = $Doc->Paragraphs;
 ShowObjs($paragraphs);

 #  Get and print the Text inside the opened file
 my $paragraphs = $Doc->Paragraphs;
 my $txt = $Doc->Range->Text;
 print $txt;
                            
 $MSWord->ActiveDocument->Close;
 $MSWord->Quit;
```

I'm getting this error code:

> OLE exception from "Microsoft Word":
>
> Command Failed
>
> Win32::OLE(0.1709) error ox800a1066
> in METHOD/PROPERTYGET "Open" at OLEWord.pl line 20

**Update:** I can open up the Word application fine, it's just when I try to open up the file that is the problem

Comment: Are you sure the file extension is 'doc'?  The open failure makes me think the file extension is docx, not doc.

Comment: I changed the file to docx and still no

Comment: I am able to open Word files (doc and docx) w/ the script above (but get failures on `$txt = $Word->Paragraphs...`).  Do you have permissions to open the file and the file isn't already open in Word somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, I created the file for test, and that the things im also not sure about, how to get the text from the word docuemtn

Comment: Make sure the file is accessible. Try to use an absolute path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have few scripts to convert DOC to various output format using [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aOLE). They usually start like this:

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';
my $wr = Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application')
    or die "Failure - word. \n";

$wr->{DisplayAlerts} = wdAlertsNone;
$wr->{Visible} = 0;

my $Doc = $wr->Documents->Open({
    FileName           => $input_file_path,
    ConfirmConversions => 0,
    AddToRecentFiles   => 0,
    Revert             => 0,
    ReadOnly           => 1,
    OpenAndRepair      => 0,
}) or exit;

...
```

Please note that `$input_file_path` has to contain absolute path to your file. You can also enable `Visible` and `DisplayAlerts` to see any error Word might give you.

**Edit:** You can traverse paragraphs using `in` enumerator:

```
use Win32::OLE qw(in);

...

my $paragraphs = $Doc->Paragraphs;
for my $par (in $paragraphs) {
    print $par->Range->Text();
}
```

Or you can use Word's own exporting method and save document as one of supported formats:

```
$Doc->SaveAs({
    FileName   => 'c:\\work\\Test.txt',
    FileFormat => wdFormatEncodedText,
});
```

The advantage of latter method is that formatting is retained if possible, which produces better results for bullets, numbering and such.

Comment: okay, so it worked at opening the file but now im getting this error: Attempt to free unreferences scalar : SV 0xb8b3c4, Perl interpreter: 0x3f3d6c.?

Comment: @Shahab - can you please show the code you are using? You can update your question.

Comment: @Shahab - please see my updated answer for paragraph traversal and exporting options. With `ShowObjs` function -- remember that `Win32::OLE` is just thin wrapper over OLE calls, so you cannot treat that as regular hashes. Weird errors are usual result.

Comment: Hmm, i like the idea of saving it as a txt file

Answer (score 1):

`Win32::OLE` can be a little funny about interaction. if anything triggers a prompt, you may get a message like this. Typically it may be that it wants to open the file read-only, for example, and put up a dialog, but these dialogs can break under the default initialization of `Win32::OLE`.

If this is the case, calling

```
Win32::OLE->Initialize(Win32::OLE::COINIT_OLEINITIALIZE);
```

before you do anything like instantiate any objects (i.e., before `Win32::OLE->new`) might do the trick.

Comment: What version of Word, Windows, and Perl are you using?

Comment: Word 2010, Windows XP and Perl 5.12

Comment: The thing is I can open up Word fine through the script. The problem is now trying to open a file once Word is open.

Comment: Hmmm, not an easy one. In the meantime, I maintain Text::Extract::Word on CPAN, which also extracts text from Word (classic .doc, but not .docx) files, but doesn't run Word or OLE to do it

Comment: hmm its a weird problem because I can open Excel and modify and print the text, its just word